# How to generate a a special sequence of numbers in R

Tags: design-patterns, numbers, sequence

Could someone please advise me on how to  to generate following numbers in R.
1
4
2
3
5
8
6
7
9
12
10
11
........I have 5000 records which I need to create this pattern of numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. I saw that the increments that you are taking are +3, -2, +1 and +2, so with a modulus operator it can be done easy.

```
vector <- vector()
vector[1] <- 1

increments <- c(3,-2,1,2)

for(i in 1:5000){
    vector[i+1] <- vector[i] + increments[((i-1)%%4)+1]
}
```

Regards.